# multiple database with same schema to use with a single app

Tags: php, database, database-schema

In recent workout with PHP, i came across a shared server.

And, the Web Host is giving limited storage per MySQL database (say 1GB).

In this case, my application will be dealing with 10k+ users and lots of site specific data, and each database can store upto 1 GB (in this case), but i am allowed to add unlimited database with 1 GB storage capacity.

So is there any way, that if my MySQL database size reaches the maximum allowed storage, and i am adding more databases, i can transfer load/query/data to that added database, and can perform query like search from both the database?

or from beginning, i can add two or more databases with same schema, so can i perform search query on both of them and retrieve data?

i.e.

**DB1** TBL1 TBL2 TBL3 
**DB2** TBL1 TBL2 TBL3

**USER1'S** INFO IS STORED IN **DB1** 
**USER2000'S** INFO IS STORED IN **DB2**

Comment: although technically you could create lots of databases with the same schema and then another database to store the list of users and which database they are in it seems like a lot of work. Look for another host that allows larger databases.

Answer (score 0):

If you know from the beginning how much data will be in the tables it is quite easy. You split the data (for example by id or by table) and your application has to have all the databases details and decide from where to fetch the data. You should consider at least a 25% reserve though.

Example:

```
database 1: table users, comments with ids 1-200.000
database 2: table posts with ids 1-10.000
database 3: table users, comments with ids 200.000-400.000
...
```

If you don't know how much data per id will be stored you should opt for a host that allows more storage per database as the handling of multiple databases that each hold different data sets will be horrific.

Comment: It will be awkward if we want to search the comments

Comment: Depends on how you want to use them. Displaying comments of a post woul not be a problem. Also searching would be okay by using UNION between the databases (if they use the same credentials).